# What is this warning->is an active destination for one of merge/mutation?

Tags: clickonce

I am getting this warning in clickhouse err logs.

```
is an active destination for one of merge/mutation (consider increasing temporary_directories_lifetime setting)
```

Also not able to find any relevant info in the documentation regarding this. What is this warning ?